# Cloning of the material is not working properly

Tags: three.js

Changing the parameters of the new material effect on the old  material stuff

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: Texture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

    material.map.repeat.set(3,3);
    material.map.offset.set(0.1,0);    

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 1, 1);    
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

mesh.position.set(-70, 0, 0);
scene.add(mesh);

var material2 = material.clone();

    material2.map.repeat.set(2,2);
    material2.map.offset.set(0.5,0);    

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 1, 1);    
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2);

mesh.position.set(70, 0, 0);
scene.add(mesh);
```

As a result, [the texture are equally](http://jsfiddle.net/alexan0308/8dyeyp4b/8/)
Maybe you need to set the repeat and offset texture in the language of geometry?

Comment: Maybe you need material.copy()

Answer (score 9):

**Material.clone** makes a shallow copy, so you end up with two different materials with the same **map**. You need to clone the texture as well if you want to set different values on it.

```
var material2 = material.clone();
material2.map = material2.map.clone();
material2.map.repeat.set(2,2);
material2.map.offset.set(0.5,0); 
material2.map.needsUpdate = true;
```